# How do I find differing words in two strings, sentence-wise?

Tags: r, text-mining, strsplit

I am comparing two similar texts. `x1` is the model text and `x2` is the text with mistakes (e.g spelling, new characters etc.). I am trying to remove words found in both texts. Since my actual text is not in English I cannot use the dictionary.

What I have tried is to step through each character of `x1` and if it is same character in `x2` then delete from `x2` and move to next character of `x1`.

Code I've been working on:

```
x1 <- "This is a test. Weather is fine. What do I do? I am clueless this coding. Let’s do this as soon as possible." 
x2 <- "This text is a test. This weather is fine. What id I do? I am clueless thius coding. Ley’s do ythis as soon as possiblke."

library(tidyverse)
x1 <- str_split(x1, "(?<=\\.)\\s")
x1 <- lapply(x1,tolower)
x2 <- str_split(x2, "(?<=\\.)\\s")
x2 <- lapply(x2,tolower)

delete_a_from_b <- function(a,b) {

  a_as_list <- str_remove_all(a,"word") %>% 
    str_split(boundary("character")) %>% unlist

  b_n <- nchar(b)

  b_as_list <- str_remove_all(b,"word") %>% 
    str_split(boundary("character")) %>% unlist

  previous_j <-1

  for (i in 1:length(a_as_list)) {
    if(previous_j > length(b_as_list)) 
      break
    for (j in previous_j:length(b_as_list)){
      if(a_as_list[[i]]==b_as_list[[j]]){
        b_as_list[[j]] <- ""
        previous_j <- j+1
        break
      }
    }
  }

  print(paste0(b_as_list,collapse = ""))
  paste0(b_as_list,collapse = "")
}

x3 <- delete_a_from_b(x1,x2)
x3 <- strsplit(x3,"\\s")
```

Output:

```
x3
[[1]]
 [1] "text"       "this"       "i"          "i"          "d?am"       "clueless"   "thius"      "coing.\"," 
 [9] "\"ley’s"    "dythsssoon" "as"         "possibk"
```

What I want as result is:  `'text' 'this' 'id'  'thius' 'ley’s' 'ythis' 'possiblke'`

Comment: What about `setdiff(
  strsplit(x2, split = "[ ?!,.]+")[[1]],
  strsplit(x1, split = "[ ?!,.]+")[[1]]
)
#> [1] "text"      "weather"   "id"        "thius"     "Ley’s"     "ythis"     "possiblke"` ? Won't take order of words into account though

Comment: also, hunspell is available for R and supports more than just english. maybe your language is supported too: http://hunspell.github.io/ & https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hunspell/index.html

Comment: @Aurèle Thank you for getting back! The problem with the code is that it is producing "weather" as an output whereas it should have been "this".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I take it you want to compare the two strings `x1` and `x2` *by sentence* - not really clear in the question. The previous solutions do not take this into account. 
Try this:

First split, both strings into sentences:

```
x1_sentences <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(x1), split = "[.?!] "))
x2_sentences <- unlist(strsplit(tolower(x2), split = "[.?!] "))
length(x1_sentences)  == length(x2_sentences) # Make sure same number of resulting sentences
```

Then, for each sentence, split the two vectors again and show difference in words:

```
for (i in 1:length(x1_sentences)) {
  x1_vector <- unlist(strsplit(x1_sentences[i], split = "[ ]"))
  x2_vector <- unlist(strsplit(x2_sentences[i], split = "[ ]"))
  print(setdiff(x2_vector, x1_vector)) # The order here is important!
}
```

Gives (which you can easily turn into a new vector):

```
[1] "text"
[1] "this"
[1] "id"
[1] "thius"
[1] "ley’s"      "ythis"      "possiblke."
```

Answer (score 1):

think i did it , is this what you need?

```
x1 <- "This is a test. Weather is fine. What do I do? I am clueless this coding. Let’s do this as soon as possible." 
x2 <- "This text is a test. This weather is fine. What id I do? I am clueless thius coding. Ley’s do ythis as soon as possiblke."

x1_w<-strsplit(paste(x1, collapse = " "), ' ')[[1]]
x2_w<-strsplit(paste(x2, collapse = " "), ' ')[[1]]
x1<- lapply(x1,tolower)
x2<- lapply(x2,tolower)

`%notin%` <- Negate(`%in%`)

x2_w[which(x2_w %notin% x1_w)]
# same as:
setdiff(x2_w,x1_w)

# out:

#> x2_w[which(x2_w %notin% x1_w)]
#[1] "text"       "id"         "thius"      "ley’s"      "ythis"      "possiblke."
```

Comment: Thank you for trying! However the problem is that the output: "weather" should not be there. "this" is missing in the output. So when x1 is compared with x2, only require the missing and non-identical words. As such "weather" is present in both x1 and x2.

Comment: Any idea why the code did not capture 'this' from the second line?